# Android ShowcaseView shadows disapear on custom circle size

Tags: android, showcaseview

I'm using Android ShowcaseView to display some small tutorials to the users of my app.

This is this library : https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

I tried to reduce the circle size by overriding these properties :

```
<dimen name="showcase_radius">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_inner">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_outer">60dp</dimen>
```

But now I don't have any shadow around my circles...

Can you help me ?